# How can I deselect a button when other consecutive button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, uistackview

I'm creating a test that has 5 buttons, each button corresponds to a specific color, the problem is that when I select a consecutive 2nd button, the previous button is still selected, how can I make my code select only one button at a time and deselect the previous one?

How can I fix this?

This is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    

    var buttonPressed: Bool = false
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonAction1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if buttonPressed {
            
            buttonPressed = false
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-5"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            buttonPressed = true
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-4"), for: .normal)
        }
      
            

        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonAction2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if buttonPressed {
            
            buttonPressed = false
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-5"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            buttonPressed = true
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-4"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonAction3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if buttonPressed {
            
            buttonPressed = false
            button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-2"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            buttonPressed = true
            button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-4"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
    
    

    
    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonAction4(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if buttonPressed {
            
            buttonPressed = false
            button4.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-3"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            buttonPressed = true
            button4.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-4"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
   
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonAction5(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if buttonPressed {
            
            buttonPressed = false
            button5.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-3"), for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            buttonPressed = true
            button5.setImage(UIImage(named: "Bolinha-4"), for: .normal)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like simple typos: You are doing `button1.setImage` in `buttonAction5` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. But you didn't actually refer to those outlets in your `IBAction` methods. For example, in `buttonAction5`, you still say `button1.setImage`, so it sets the image of `button1` instead. Oh and I just noticed, you also need 5 different `buttonPressed` variables if you want to control them separately. You might want to consider using an array to store the states and buttons, and use tags to identify the buttons instead.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I know that perhaps I'm not supposed to ask this in the comments, but now my next problem is that when I click the 2nd button, for example, I click button1 and then button2, both buttons are selected, how can I unselect a previous pressed button so only one button can remain altered in the screen?                                                                                                                            Ps: If you think that is more appropriate to StackOverflow I can create another question

Comment: You could set a tag value for each button. When one button is pressed, you can save the current tag and then do a for loop on all your buttons and deselect those that have different tags than the one you previously saved.

Comment: Thx for the advice, I'm still a beginner/intermediate, so I'm not fully certain how exactly to make that, even though seems like a good idea, I'll try,  so... create a tag value for each button -> set a value for the tag representing the button that was pressed -> Create an array loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are going to accomplish is called *Radio Buttons*, unfortunately iOS (unlike macOS) doesn't provide this functionality.

My suggestion takes advantage of the option to assign different images to different states in Interface Builder – in this case the `Default` and `Selected` state – and to create an outlet collection, an array representing a sequence of UI elements of the same type.

The suggestion doesn't support an empty selection, by default the first button is selected.

---

- In ViewController

  - create an outlet collection

    ```
    @IBOutlet var buttons : [UIButton]!
    ```
  - and one `IBAction`

    ```
     @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) { }
    ```
- In Interface Buider

  - set the images to the `Default` and `Selected` states of each button in the Attribute Inspector.
  - connect the buttons in the proper order to the outlet collection.
  - assign the tags 0 to 4 to the buttons in the same order.
  - connect all buttons also to the (same) IBAction.
- In ViewController

  - create a property for the tag of the currently selected button

    ```
     var selectedButton = 0
    ```
  - in viewDidLoad select the first button

    ```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         buttons[selectedButton].isSelected = true
     }
    ```
  - Complete the IBAction, it deselects the previous button and selects the current.

    ```
     @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
         let tag = sender.tag
         buttons[selectedButton].isSelected = false
         buttons[tag].isSelected = true
         selectedButton = tag
     }
    ```

Answer (score 0):

let's consider you have named your buttons as follows: 1st button: "opt1Button", 2nd button: "opt2Button", 3rd button: "opt3Button" and so on...
create an IBAction with name "optionSelected" The function will look like:
@IBAction func optionSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    opt1Button.isSelected = false
    opt2Button.isSelected = false
    opt3Button.isSelected = false
    opt4Button.isSelected = false
    opt5Button.isSelected = false
    
    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

As soon any of the options is selected all the buttons will go to 'isSelected' false condition i.e all the buttons will be deselected at first and the selected button will be marked as selected. Same process will be followed again when any of the button is selected, everything will get deselected and the button user has pressed will be marked as selected.

Found this answer from (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685124) and it worked for me.